# Complex Analysis question. (Maximum Modulus Principle?)

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is an entire function and $|f(z)| \,\leq\, e^{\Re(z)}$ for all complex $z$.
Prove that there exists some complex $\lambda$ such that $f(z) = λe^z.$

I tried to make sense of this question using Maximum Modulus principle, while getting stuck how to go to the conclusion on the second line.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the entire function $f(z)e^{-z}$?

Comment: A fun question. Somehow I'd never thought of this variant... Thanks for asking this! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $$|f(z)|\le e^{\text{Re}(z)}\implies \left| \frac{f(z)}{e^z}\right|\le 1$$

Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$, which is entire and bounded, and apply Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Well yes, but some would say that's more than a hint my friend. But, ta-da: +1

Comment: @zhw. Z-Man!  It's nice to see you here and I hope that you're doing well.  As for  the issue of the "hint," some others would say "I just don't quite get it."   Any way ...